# EF Core: Foreign key returns null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, xamarin

I'm trying to access a foreign key (owner) in xamarin forms, but it only returns `null`. According to many other questions here at stack it seems that I have to use lazy loading or Eager loading to get data from foreign key.

As lazy loading is not implemented in Core yet, I have tried to use Eager Loading instead, but I still get the `null` value both in xamarin forms and on backend.

My Model:

```
public class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BuildingName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int BuildingYear { get; set; }
    public bool BuildingBool { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser Owner { get; set; }
}
```

My Repository:

```
public IEnumerable<Building> GetAll()
{
    return _context.buildings.Include(b => b.Owner).ToList();
}
```

My Controller:

```
 public IEnumerable<Building> Get(Building value)
 {
     return _BuildingRepository.GetAll();
 }
```

My DbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Building> buildings { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

This is how the data looks like in the database:
[image]

Do I need something else than the `Include(b => b.Owner)` in my repository to get it to work?

Comment: is Owner there in the building model??

Comment: yes, Owner is an ApplicationUser in the building model if that's what you mean

Comment: Need more code. How is the relationship set up? A get all method like that will load ALL buildings and owners into memory. Which sucks btw likelihood yagni. Have more specialized queries. But ok this isn't codereview! :p

Comment: @ebk can you include you context file, insure that the data is in the database, and include the method which shows how you save the file please.

Comment: you need to include OwnerId property in Building

Comment: what you are referring to is not the foreign key, but (in EF terms) the navigation property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see foreign key property in your Building model, only navigation property.

I think you should include:

```
public int OwnerId { get; set; }
```

in Building class.